# Nagios NRPE: Command not defined

Tags: nagios, nrpe

In my `nrpe_local.cfg` added following command:

```
command[check_mycommand]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_command 30 35
```

and then restarted nrpe daemon.

When I execute this command using `nrpe` I'm getting the following error:

```
NRPE: Command 'check_mycommand' not defined
```

I used following command to execute:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H hostname -c check_mycommand
```

I am unable to get any clue.

In my `nrpe_local.cfg` there are 10 more commands added and they are working properly.

Answer (score 3):

> In my nrpe_local.cfg added following command:> 
>   `command[check_mycommand]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_command 30 35`

Try :

```
command[check_mycommand]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_command -w (warningTreshold) -c (criticalTreshold)
/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server restart
```

And indeed kill all other daemons of nrpe which are already running.
The cause could be it is already running by different users which may cause conflicts.
eg. nagios-nrpe-server is running under user root and under user nagios

Also make sure you added your Nagios server's IP address to the allowed_hosts in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg :

```
allowed_hosts=<ip address of nagios server>
```

Else you won't be able to execute external commands with NRPE from Nagios.

Answer (score 3):

Hello i solved this problem by adding the **local address** in the configuration file so `nrpe.cfg`
`allowed_host = 127.0.0.1`, `xxxx` where `xxxx` is the IP of my **nagios server**.
You should also be defined command `[check_disk]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk-w 20%-c 10%-p /var`

is very important that the command name `[check_disk]` is the same as that indicated on the route

Thanks to this, my problem was solved and I now have an excellent monitoring.

Yilmar Hernández

Answer (score 3):

Your command in `nrpe.cfg` should look like this:

```
command[check_mycommand]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_command -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

then, your service in `services.cfg` file (or whatever it's name) check should look like this:

```
define service{
   servicegroups        Basic Functionality
   host_name            localhost
   service_description  Mycommand
   check_command        check_nrpe!check_mycommand -a '-w 30 -c 35'
   use                  generic-service
}
```

Please let me know if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you start NRPE daemon with the correct config file? (nrpe -c config_file -d) 
The config file you are using there is nagios_local.conf or nrpe_local.cfg?

Comment: Update my question because of mistakes. I am using nrpe_local.conf only. When I ran command nrpe -c nrep_local.conf not getting any output. As I told there are some other commands defined in nrep_local.cfg and they are working without any issue. The new command which I added is only not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure you killed off all the old daemons, including any forks.
2. After a clean restart of NRPE, check /var/log/messages for any errors?!  Especially things like "NRPE: ERROR - can not bind to port/port already in use".
3. Are you positive that an inetd controlled NRPE is not being used?
4. If the above doesn't help, do step 1 again, then when starting NRPE do not include the '-d' flag and exam the output.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by adding the below lines to my `nrpe.cfg` file and restarting the `nrpe`. Basically, we are telling to nagios to recognize the commands that we are running.

```
command[check_var]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /var
command[check_slash]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /
command[check_ssh]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh $ARG1$
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i got this error and was able to solve it : 
in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg youll see :

```
command[check_var]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /var
command[check_slash]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /
command[check_ssh]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh $ARG1$
```

but im sure you got confiused and set : 
commend.cfg with : check_disk and not check_slash

see that the line says "  command[check_slash] " this is what the command.cfg wants to get.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and checking in syslog I could see that nrpe had write problems in /var/run/

```
Nov  6 08:30:05 xxxxxx nrpe[39777]: Cannot write to pidfile '/var/run/nrpe.pid' - check your privileges.
```

I found here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nagios-nrpe/+bug/957367

that the solution was quiet simple. Just edit nrpe.cfg and change:

```
pid_file=/var/run/nrpe.pid
```

to

```
pid_file=/var/run/nagios/nrpe.pid
```

kill nrpe manually and start it again with /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start

It just worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably will help to someone.

In my case problem was in typo.
I created file `/etc/nrpe.d/commands.cgf` instead of `/etc/nrpe.d/commands.cfg` ;)